# why my WP7 Timer sometimes stops to count?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i have a problem with a application. this application simply shows a number value every second. you can see it as a countdown. the problem is, that this `Timer` sometimes stop to tick and i dont know why. where is my code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}
```

i start the timer afte the Loaded event:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer t1 = new Timer(TimerCall);
    t1.Change(0, 1000);
}
```

and here is the method which chanes the text:

```
private void TimerCall(object state)
{
     TextField.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
    {
        TextField.Text = "some text change";
    }); 
}
```

**I dont understand why this sometimes stops**

Comment: Have you tried DispatcherTimer? It already does the Invoking and might be more suitable.

Comment: I'm not a wp developer, but at first glance it appears that `t1` should be declared in the class scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.fwic.net/Resources/FusionWareIntegrationBlogs/tabid/116/EntryId/80/Windows-Phone-7-5-A-Stopwatch-Now-What-Do-I-Do.aspx) especially the section on The Tombstone

Next to the fact that the Timer is a local variable instead of a class member, you might be running into the tomb stoning process. The article explains this quite well.